# How can I prove that $(X,τ)$ is a Hausdorff topological space?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, separation-axioms, product-space

Let $(X_1,τ_1)$ is a Hausdorff topological space and $(X_2,τ_2)$ is a Hausdorff topological space and $X=X_1\times X_2$ and $τ$ The product topology

How can I prove that $(X,τ)$ is a Hausdorff topological space ?

Comment: You need to be able to separate any two points. Pick two different points in $X$ - for the moment, suppose the points differ in both coordinates. If you project onto either coordinate, you can separate the two points. Can you use that to separate the two points in $X$?

Comment: IMO it is more usual to use $X_1\times X_2$ `$X_1\times X_2$` for the Cartesian product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $(x_1,x_2)$, $(x_1',x_2')$ be distinct points in $X_1\times X_2$. Then $x_1\ne x_1'$ or $x_2\ne x_2'$; without loss of generality we can assume the former. Since $X_1$ is Hausdorff, we may choose disjoint neighborhoods $U,V\subset X_1$ such that $x_1\in U$ and $x_1'\in U'$. If $x_2\ne x_2'$ then choose disjoint neighborhoods $V,V'$ of $x_2,x_2'$ in $X_2$; else set $V=V'=X_2$. Then $(x_1,x_2)\in U\times V$, $(x_1',x_2')\in U'\times V'$, and
$$(U\times V)\cap(U'\times V') = (U\cap U')\times (V\cap V') = \varnothing, $$
so that $X_1\times X_2$ is Hausdorff.